# URL Regex for Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to compare webpage URLs using regex. I am using the below method.

```
regex_url = r'https://www.website.com/books/\w{8}$'
is_read = re.match(regex_url, request.url) is not None
if not is_read:
     add_to_read(token)
```

Everything works well for the above regex. But there is a new URL pattern now which I cant seem to get the regex right.

The new URL pattern is

```
https://www.website.com/books/Ab7us83xI?varient=web
```

9 characters followed by a question mark and then the word 'varient' and then '=web'. Can anyone help me get the correct regex for this?

Only the first 9 characters change every time. Apologies if this is a stupid question.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Jay, Is there a reason why you do not want to use `urlparse` from `urllib.parse` and instead want your own regex? What you seem to care about is the `path` segment of the URL. `?K=V` are `query` segments of the URL.

Comment: Hi Sudheesh. Thank you for your response. I will certainly consider this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
https://www.website.com/books/\w{9}\?varient=web$

\w{9} - match 9 characters
\?    - match question mark
varient=web - match varient=web
```